# How can I delete an asp.net identity 2.2.1 user in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I am using asp.net identity 2.2.1 and I want to delete a user when he/she tries to hit a specific action method in one of none account controllers. Being into many SO question each of them points to a version dependent solution and frankly I couldn't find a to the point answer. 
Why there is no plain and simple documentation on deleting an identity user and most importantly ***why this feature is not part of the identity it self?***

Please note that I am using individual user accounts for external logins no local login is allowed.

My identity.cofig files looks like below:

```
namespace SocialManager
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = false
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    // Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`UserManager` has [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497527(v=vs.108).aspx) that looks like this:

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> DeleteAsync(TUser user)
```

Use it to delete user record.

Update:

here is how to delete a user:

```
// id is id of the user to be deleted.
var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id); //use async find
var result = await userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    // user is deleted
}
```

Comment: What is TUser? and how can I get it?

Comment: `TUser` is a generic parameter for the method. For your case this will be `ApplicationUser`

Comment: Can't you give a detailed answer? I am new to asp.net and Identity

Comment: I can't use userManager the way you did although I have using microsoft.asp.identity in place

Comment: You shown `ApplicationUserManager` code in the question. Why can't you use it?

Comment: I am using it in another controller

Comment: Why not use it in every place where you need it? it is not like you have to pay for every instance of this class.

Comment: So why I see the intellisense doesn't show anything why I type UserManager.

Comment: I can't know that, I don't see your controllers.